# HIGHESTMODSEQ response from gmail

Tags: python, gmail, imap, twisted

I have a python script that uses a twisted imap4.IMAP4Client to check for new emails in a gmail account. It does so every ~30 seconds. It has been running fine for months.

Starting June 11, I began to see this message after the `search("(UNSEEN)")` call:

```
Unhandled unsolicited response: ['OK', ['HIGHESTMODSEQ', '1234567']]
```

This message appears at every check for new messages now.

What does this message mean? Is it anything to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HIGHESTMODSEQ is a protocol extension you can ignore. It is documented in RFC4551.

Comment: I did in fact look at that document in my web searches, but it made no sense to me. I don't know what a "mod-sequence" on a mail server is in the first place..

Comment: The full protocol extension adds the concept of a 'modification sequence'.  Every time a message is changed (eg, changed flags), a sequence number is incremented and attached to the change.  Then, you can ask the server for all changes since a certain modseq.  HIGHESTMODSEQ lets you know what the highest sequence currently in the mailbox is.  If it hasn't changed since last time you looked at it, nothing has changed in the mailbox.  Make sense?

Comment: In general, the extensions are designed in such a way as to make them backward-compatible. You are not supposed to die on untagged OK with an unrecognized response kind, as in this situation.

Comment: Right, it doesn't die. It just puts messages in the log file that make it look like something weird is going on, especially since it just "turned on" at some point. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just silly log noise.  The IMAP4 client parser is telling you the server sent it something it didn't expect and doesn't really know how to handle.  So it is handling it by logging that message.

Off the top of my head, I have no idea what HIGHESTMODSEQ is for, but if you don't care about that information either, then you can just ignore this.  If you do care about it, you can contribute a patch to Twisted to add support for this kind of unsolicited response. :)